# On the percentage of oxygen in the atmosphere

Tags: atmosphere, oxygen

The percentage of oxygen in the atmosphere is 21 percent, according to NASA.gov. I was trying to make a mathematical calculation about oxygen consumption of humans, when I realised that there is a gap in my understanding of the above mentioned fact. Is 21% of the MASS of the atmosphere that of oxygen, or is 21% of the VOLUME of the atmosphere that of oxygen? The mass is not evenly distributed in the atmosphere, and the volume of it is fixed. And for that matter, I have another question, how exactly is the percentage of oxygen in the atmosphere calculated?

Comment: Oxygen can be "measured" indirectly using spectrometry and a set of known references with calibrated gas.  See the Scripps Program here: https://scrippso2.ucsd.edu/what-we-do.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The atmosphere is 20.95% Oxygen by volume, on a dry basis (i.e. without any water vapor).  See [here](http://www.atmo.arizona.edu/students/courselinks/fall16/atmo336/lectures/sec1/composition.html) for detailed composition information.

Your second question, how is the oxygen percentage calculated, is misguided I believe.  The composition of the atmosphere is measured with gas analyzers, not calculated.

Comment: Thank you for considering my questions and answering them, I appreciate it!